# Perpetual motion machine

Tags: energy, engineering

Which are the minimal changes in the physical laws in order to make possible a perpetual motion machine?

Comment: And here you might be able to find people who would be eager to make perpetual motion machine possible (in your world). By the way, the law that you would want to overthrow is [law of conservation of energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy)

Comment: If my previous comment makes no sense, it is because I was addressing ideas in the original post before the OP edited the post and deleted those ideas. :-)

Comment: @Amadeus note that you can delete *your own* comment any time.

Answer (score 2):

Perpetual motion machines contradict the laws of thermodynamics and the conservation of mass energy.

Is it possible to build one? No

Is a perpetual motion motion machine a source of infinite energy? No

However, a source of infinite energy might tentatively qualify as a perpetual motion machine (although it's still a silly idea)

Since perpetual motion machines are impossible, for them to be possible the physical principles underlying their function and operations would have to be contrary to thermodynamics and the conservation of mass energy. Possibly if the machine was a source of infinite energy. Although there would be the small engineering problem of making sure it never wore out, sprung leaks or became dirty. All of which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

There are no perpetual motion machines.

Every known object in the entire universe is subject to the laws of thermodynamics.  One of those laws is that entropy always increases.  If entropy is increasing, perpetual motion is impossible unless you have an external source of energy feeding it (such as gasoline being fed into a motor).

The assertion that there are no perpetual motion machines is so strong that the patent office has a standing policy to not even *look* at a patent that claims perpetual motion.  Any patent that makes that claim is simply dismissed without further study.

If you could make a perpetual motion machine that generated energy, you would quickly become the richest person alive.  The fact that the richest people alive aren't relying on perpetual motion machines is very strong evidence that they have not been made.

Idealized physics permits perpetual motion that does no work.  It gets away with this by permitting things like friction-less devices and perfect vacuums and whatnot.  These devices are not known to exist in the real world.  Even quantum mechanical devices, which are arguably the best chance for perpetual motion, must deal with entropic losses due to random collisions with molecules because we can't make a perfect vacuum (not even the deep of space is a perfect vacuum.  There's a bit of hydrogen out there).

There is a cosmological theory that the universe is a perpetual motion machine that does no work.  This device would expand and crunch over and over for all time.  However, even among those who believe this theory, there is still a near universal acceptance that subsets of the universe (i.e. any piece of the universe) cannot possibly be perpetual motion.

Feel free to look for perpetual motion machines.  Science has been wrong in the past.  For all we know it could be wrong here.  It may be possible to pray for a perpetual motion machine for all we know.  However, do choose to spend your time wisely:  millions upon millions of scientist-hours have been spent exploring countless potential leads -- none of them have lead to perpetual motion yet.

Comment: Your third paragraph is essentially saying PMMs don't exist because they haven't been invented yet

Comment: @nzaman I intended that to be a vacuous if statement, similar to "If you could turn lead into gold..."  I suppose I might need to be more clear, as to avoid providing false hopes.

Answer (score -1):

While it is possible to Build a machine that uses Gravity to gain a mechanical appearance of perpetual motion. The out put of energy is so small as to be non existent.

Most use a trick based around different distances from center for a lever and applied force. Simple answer how it works. Descending arms have longer fulcrum arm there for more leverage.

You still have to raise the weights on the other side so your output is The difference between descending arm and ascending arm. You have to make a HUGE machine to get any real out put more then the loss to friction.

Comment: There can be no output energy from the machine you describe. Unless you hide a motor in it...

Comment: @L.Dutch Maybe he means the orbits of planets, moons , etc. The problem is that the moment you extract energy from an orbit, the orbit decays and the orbiting body begins to fall towards the orbited body, shrinking and shrinking it until the bodies collide. i.e. , an orbit is just momentum not being spent

Comment: @TheoclesofSaturn, he talks about levers...

Comment: @L.Dutch , Good point , Nevermind

Comment: @L.Dutch I understand that you did not read the first sentence. 
 While it is possible to Build a machine that uses Gravity to gain a mechanical appearance of perpetual motion.     
Lets cover that thought again...
appearance Looks like not but really... 
uses Gravity... Gravity is an input force so it is adding a force.
[Bhaskara's Wheel]   (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50Aag0J0Qe4) takes gravity tries to use it to gain a advantage.